# 'for' loop error with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I want to have an NSTimer that would fire a selector every x seconds if a certain condition (the selector is `NO`) is true. 
The value of x should change like this - 10, 20, 40, 60, 120.

If the selector changes to `YES` (it returns a `BOOL`) the timer should stop and change it's initial time to 10 seconds.

I've got this code for a timer:

```
double i;
for (i= 10.0; i < maxInternetCheckTime; i++) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkForInternetConnection)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
    NSLog(@"Timer is %f seconds", i);
}
```

But the output I get is just not what I intended to see in the beginning:

```
2012-12-21 19:25:48.351 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 10.000000 seconds
2012-12-21 19:25:48.352 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 11.000000 seconds
2012-12-21 19:25:48.352 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 12.000000 seconds
2012-12-21 19:25:48.352 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 13.000000 seconds
2012-12-21 19:25:48.352 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 14.000000 seconds
2012-12-21 19:25:48.352 Custom Queue[3157:c07] Timer is 15.000000 seconds
```

And so on.
What am I doing wrong in this pretty trivial task?

Comment: Why is that crazy output? Your log is just logging the value of i, which starts at 10 and goes up by 1 for each loop.

Comment: I think he's expecting it to block.

Comment: @jrturton Yes sir, I know that, but if you the conditions of my task, that's not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>       for (i= 10.0; i < maxInternetCheckTime; i++) {
>          [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i
> ```

You are scheduling a set of 10 timers at the same moment to be executed after: 10, 11, 12,13, etc seconds.

You need just one timer to start with:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(checkForInternetConnection:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

then in `checkForInternetConnection` you schedule a new one if needed:

```
-(void)checkForInternetConnection:(NSTimer*)firedTimer {

   float interval = firedTimer.timeInterval;
   interval *= 2;

   if (<CONDITION>) {
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(checkForInternetConnection)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
   }
 }
```

I hope the logic is clear:

1. you schedule a check;
2. you do the check;
3. if check is not ok, you schedule a new one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was just typing more or less this exact same thing, but you beat me to it! Nice to see someone putting an explanation rather than just a dump of code

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, but how do I increase the value of `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` each time? I should have it 10 at the first time, 20 at the second time, 40 at the third time and so on.

Comment: @SergiusGee: please see my edit; I am just doubling the timer interval each time; if you want a finer control, you can create an NSArray of times, then index into it by keeping a counter to the last used index.

Comment: @sergio Thanks for such a verbose and great answer! Awesome!

Answer (score -1):

You are printing `i`, which is increased by 1 in every cycle beginning from 10. This is the correct output.

Comment: I know, but if you read the conditions of my task, that's not the thing I want.

Comment: You said "But the output I get is just crazy:". It isn't crazy, maybe you should have read your question before posting it.

Comment: Crazy to the relation of what I intended to get, no to the fact that it's wrong. Can NSLog be wrong? I doubt it. Thanks for downvoting the post, though

Comment: Though you are incorrect, if you make an edit to your post, I'll remove the downvote

Comment: We have a deal :) I can't remove the downvote for your post unless it's edited

Comment: But just because Xmas is close :) ... Edited